# Questions about the concept of strong Markov property

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am trying to understand the concept of strong Markov property quoted from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property#Strong_Markov_Property):

> Suppose that $X=(X_t:t\geq 0)$ is a
>   stochastic process on a probability
>   space
>   $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ with
>   natural filtration
>   $\{\mathcal{F}\}_{t\geq 0}$. Then $X$
>   is said to have the strong Markov
>   property if, for each stopping time
>   $\tau$, conditioned on the event
>   $\{\tau < \infty\}$, the process
>   $X_{\tau + \cdot}$ (which maybe needs
>   to be defined) is independent from
>   $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}:=\{A \in  \mathcal{F}: \tau \cap A \in  \mathcal{F}_t ,\, \ t \geq 0\}$ and
>   $X_{\tau + t} − X_{\tau}$ has the same
>   distribution as $X_t$ for each $t \geq  0$.

Here are some questions that make me stuck:

1. In $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}:=\{A \in
       \mathcal{F}: \tau \cap A \in
       \mathcal{F}_t ,\, \ t \geq 0\} $,
   what does $\tau \cap A $ mean?
   $\tau$ is a stopping time and
   therefore a random variable and $A$
   is a $\mathcal{F}$-measurable
   subset, but what does $\tau \cap A$
   mean?
2. How is the process $X_{\tau + \cdot}$ defined from the process $X_{\cdot}$ ? Is it the translated
   version of the latter by $\tau$?
3. How is the conditional independence
   between a process, such as $X_{\tau
       + \cdot}$,  and the sigma algebra, such as $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$, given
   an event, such as $\{\tau <
       \infty\}$, defined?

   Related question, is independence
   between a random variable and a
   sigma algebra defined as
   independence between the sigma
   algebra of the random variable and
   the sigma algebra?
4. Is "$X_{\tau+ t}  − X_{\tau}$ has the
   same distribution as $X_t$ for each
   $t \geq 0$" also conditional on the
   event $\{\tau < \infty\}$?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: After reading that I think, really, you should be learning about the strong Markov property from somewhere other than Wikipedia.

Comment: @George: I tried to look up in several books, many of which are just talking about the theorem of strong Markov property for Brownian motion. One (Lamperti's book) uses some notation that I don't understand yet. Maybe I will sometime but who knows. So I very much appreciate some nice and clear references to clear things up.

Comment: I don't have time to write up a proper answer now, but I do have a definition of the strong Markov property on my blog (but it assumes a good knowledge of measure-theoretic probability theory) http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/07/19/properties-of-feller-processes/#scn_fpp_def1

Comment: And in that Wikipedia page, they don't say what notation they are using for the bits you labeled (1) and (2), and it looks weird. (4) is just plain wrong.

Comment: @George: Thanks for your blog! In the third paragraph there, "Recall that the law of an inhomogeneous Markov process $X$ is described by a transition function ${\{P_t\}_{t\ge0}}$ on some measurable space ${(E,\mathcal{E})}$." Do you mean "inhomogeneous" or "homogenenous"?

Comment: I meant homogeneous (Thanks. I'll fix it)

Comment: @George: is transition function only used for Markov process? If not, what is its general purpose?

Comment: Tom - yes. Transition functions are used to define Markov processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a less garbled version of the Wikipedia definition. (Use TheBridge's correction for the definition of ${\cal F}_\tau$.) 
  The post-$\tau$ process $X_{\tau+\cdot}$ is defined on the event $\{\tau<\infty\}$ by
$$
X_{\tau+t}(\omega) = X_{\tau(\omega)+t}(\omega),\qquad t\ge 0,
$$
for  $\omega\in\{\tau<\infty\}$. One way to state the strong Markov property is this: The conditional distribution of $X_{\tau+\cdot}$ given ${\cal F}_\tau$ is (a.s.) equal to the conditional distribution of 
$X_{\tau+\cdot}$ given $\sigma\{X_\tau\}$, on the event $\{\tau<\infty\}$. More precisely,
$$
P[ X_{\tau+t}\in B|{\cal F}_\tau] = P[ X_{\tau+t}\in B|X_\tau],\qquad \hbox{almost surely on }\{\tau<\infty\},
$$
for all $t\ge 0$, and all measurable subsets $B$ of the state space of $X$.

This is equivalent to the statement that $X_{\tau+\cdot}$ and ${\cal F}_\tau$ are conditionally independent, given $X_\tau$:
$$
P[ F\cap \{X_{\tau+t}\in B\}|X_\tau] = P[ F|X_\tau]\cdot P[X_{\tau+t}\in B|X_\tau],\qquad \hbox{almost surely on }\{\tau<\infty\},
$$

Comment: The condition you wrote after your "More precisely" characterizes the conditional distribution of the random variable $X_{\tau+t}$ conditionally on $\mathcal{F}_\tau$, for every $t\ge0$. This is strictly weaker than the property of the conditional distribution of the process $X_{\tau+\cdot}$ conditionally on $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ that is required for $X$ to be strong Markov.

Comment: Good point!  That really should be
$$
P[ G|{\cal F}_\tau] = P[ G|X_\tau],\qquad \hbox{almost surely on }\{\tau<\infty\},\leqno(*)
$$
for all events $G$  in the $\sigma$-field generated by $X_{\tau+\cdot}$, and similarly for the conditional independence form of the property.

On the other hand, if the weaker form found  in my first post holds {\it for all\/} stopping times, then so does the stronger form ($*$).

Comment: D Sure, by the chain rule for conditional probabilities. But my point is that, since the OP asks for clear and explicit definitions and proofs about a notion he/she is trying to understand in depth, you might want to add to your post an expanded version of the remark you made in the last sentence of your comment.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one the notation is wrong it should I think $A\cap\{\tau\le t\}\in\mathcal{F}_t$ instead of $A\cap\tau$.

And for the fourth point, look at George Lowther comments below, that fully address the problematic.

Regard

Comment: No, the fourth point is saying that it has identical increments, which is true for Levy processes, but not part of the strong Markov property.

Comment: In fact, the fourth point on its own implies that it is a Levy process starting from zero.

Comment: You are right how I missed that I edit my post accordingly

Comment: I'm guessing, but I think the person who wrote that Wikipedia entry copied a statement from somewhere which was only dealing with Levy processes, and also made some typos.